# $f \in S \rightarrow \hat f \in S$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $S$ be the Schwartz space and $ \hat f$ be the Fourier transform of $f$.

I hope to prove that $f \in S \rightarrow \hat f \in S$.

I know some properties about Fourier transform but I do not know how to prove that.

Comment: This follows immediately from the fact that the Fourier transform sends differentiation to multiplication by $\omega$ and multiplication by $x$ to differentiation.

Comment: I know $y^aD^bF(f)(y)=F(D^ax^bf(y))$ but why does it say '$sup|F(D^ax^bf(y))|<\infty$'?

Comment: I know $yaDbF(f)(y)=F(Daxbf(x))$ but why does it say '$sup|F(Daxbf(x))|$<∞'?

Comment: I know $y^aD^bF(f)(y)=F(D^ax^bf(x))$ but why does it say '$sup|F(D^ax^bf(x))|<\infty$'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove this via manipulating certain estimates under the integral. But I suggest you to take a look at this [article](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erbm/iml90.pdf). The proof given by Melrose (page 19) is quite illuminating. You should really try to prove this kind of thing yourself once, because otherwise the knowledge would not stay.

Comment: I think I understand it. thanks.